# create a "bind" mount once and reuse in multiple container

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I need to start multiple container on my developer machine and mount a folder on host machine to all containers.

we know that we can create volumes at once and reuse them in multiple mount commands as source but is it possible to create bind mounts also and reuse them

for example this is a valid way to share a volumne

```
docker volume create not-what-i-need

docker run -d -t \
    --name container1 \
    --mount source=not-what-i-need, target=/home/appuser/abc \
    image1
docker run -d -t \
    --name container2 \
    --mount source=not-what-i-need, target=/home/appuser/abc \
    image2
```

But what I actually want to do is define mount once and reuse in in all below container creations

```
 docker run -d -t \
        --name container1 \
        --mount type=bind,source=/host-machine/folder1, target=/home/appuser/abc \
        image1
    docker run -d -t \
        --name container2 \
        --mount type=bind, source=/host-machine/folder1, target=/home/appuser/abc \
        image2
```

Comment: I might use the shorter `docker run -v /host-machine/folder1:/home/appuser/abc`, but your last example looks fine (if you remove the extra spaces from the `--mount` options).  What problem are you running into?

Comment: No problem. In real scenario, I have 3  mount location with very long folder path on host machine and I need to start almost 15 containers on local developer machine. I'm not using docker-compose for a different reason. so all these steps are mentioned in one shell script. The actual script is getting too big because of 3 same bind-mounts with long absolute-path repeated 15 times.. Thats why If you check the quesiton, I asked if I can create once and reuse the reference like we do in docker-volume in first example

Comment: In the context of a script, can you set a shell variable to the host path (or reference a variable like `$PWD`)?  Do the containers really need to access the same files; how do you manage file locking, scaling, permissions, and other constraints?

Comment: its for local developer machines only. Where there is no k8s cluster, and we are managing all the required-services usign docker-contaniner.  so few certs and other common 'read-only things are placed at predefined locations. which in non-developer-local-environments are usually provided in k8s config & secrets. and some mechanism for service-discovery.